# Q learning transition matrix trouble

Tags: machine-learning, q-learning

First, apologies if this isn't the right forum for my question -- let me know if there's a better place.

I'm trying to implement Q learning on a two-dimensional grid world, where the agent has four actions available -- movement to the left, right, up, or down. A $4 \times 4$ transition matrix $T$ gives the probability the agent moves in the intended direction. So if $T$ is the identity matrix, and the agent intends to move left, it will move left $100 \%$ of the time; but $T$ can be modified such that the agent moves left $90 \%$ of the time, and up $10 \%$ of the time, etc.

My implementation does the following:

> 1. initializes Q values to 0
> 2. places agent in a randomized start location $s$
> 3. agent chooses an action $a$ according to an epsilon-greedy strategy
> 4. the transition matrix is used to determine which direction $i$ the agent actually ends up moving
> 5. agent moves in direction $i$, ends up in state $s'$, collects some reward $r$, and the Q value $Q(s, a)$ is updated
> 6. repeat steps 3, 4, 5 as necessary

When $T$ is the identity matrix, my implementation returns the correct answer. When I change $T$, my implementation still returns the answer as though $T$ is the identity.

I've spent a lot of time reviewing step 4 above and believe my implementation is correct. When I choose $T$ such that the agent moves in the intended direction $90 \%$ of the time, then $a$ and $i$ match $90 \%$ of the time, exactly as intended.

Is there anywhere else this issue could be coming from?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "my implementation still returns the answer as though  is the identity"? Does it render the same Q-values or the same behaviour?